# Ignore timezone offset portion of date time stamp pandas parse_dates

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col = 'endDate', parse_dates = True)
```

endDate in csv

```
2016-05-06 15:01:01 -0400
```

endDate index for data frame in pandas after import

```
2016-05-06 19:01:01
```

How do I ignore the -0400 offset in the csv?

Comment: You'd have to not parse as dates initially and strip the timezone info so `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col = 'endDate')` and then `df.index = df.index.str.replace(' -0400','')` and convert using `to_datetime` `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` should work. Is the timezone value the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
filename = '/path/to/file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='endDate', parse_dates=['endDate'],
                 date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]))
```

Test:

```
data = """\
endDate,val
2016-05-06 15:01:01 -0400,11
2016-05-06 20:20:20 -0100,12
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col='endDate', parse_dates=['endDate'],
                 date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]))
```

Output:

```
In [119]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col='endDate', parse_dates=['endDate'],
   .....:                  date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]))

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
                     val
endDate
2016-05-06 15:01:01   11
2016-05-06 20:20:20   12
```

Comment: where would i put the path to the data.csv file in the code?

Comment: @RyanPraskievicz, i've updated my answer - `pd.read_csv(filename, ...)`

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing here is to not parse initially so you can strip the timezone information away and then convert:

```
In [14]:
t="""date
2016-05-06 15:01:01 -0400"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),index_col=[0])
df.index = df.index.str.rsplit().str[0:-1].str.join(' ')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df

Out[14]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2016-05-06 15:01:01]
```

So here the dates import as `str` so we now remove the timezone using `str.rsplit` and then join again but without the timezone info. We can then use `to_datetime` to convert to `datetime`

Comment: thanks for the comment, I was able to get it to work perfectly with my data. In your answer where does data.csv go in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension together with str.split().

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'endDate': ['2016-05-06 15:01:01 -0400', '2016-05-06 16:01:01 -0400']})

df['endDate'] = pd.to_datetime([date + " " + time 
                                for date, time, _ in df.endDate.str.split()])

>>> df
              endDate
0 2016-05-06 15:01:01
1 2016-05-06 16:01:01
```

Comment: when I used my csv file  `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")` (not the endDate you specified) with the code in your answer I get this error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas. How can I make the endDate a string?

Comment: Don't parse the dates.