# Pandas, Psycopg2, Timezone Offset

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, pandas, timezone-offset

I'm connecting to a postgres db using psycopg2 and then manipulating data in pandas and plotting the results with matplotlib.

From the postgres database I can get the timezone offset hour e.g. `-7`, `-6` etc.
I would like to convert my timestamp to the appropriate timezone using the tzoffset field. I thought I could convert it into a timedelta but no such luck. Any help?

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149603/ignore-timezone-offset-portion-of-date-time-stamp-pandas-parse-dates) seems to show something similar using a csv import into pandas so I can't imagine it's too difficult but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
conn = pg.connect(
user = dbinfo.username,
host = dbinfo.hostname,
database = dbinfo.path[1:],
password = dbinfo.password,
)

sql = """

SELECT
some_TIMESTAMP as starttime,
tzoffset AS tzoffset (*COMES OUT AS `-7`*)
FROM
    table"""
###Connection to the database
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conn)
```

Comment: Just to say, the timestamps are stored natively in `utc` and the offset calculated in postgres based on location

Comment: I hacked this problem by converting the tzoffset value to an int, then to a timedelta using `pd.timedelta(column,h)` and adding to the UTC timestamp. It works because of the tz i'm working with but is in no way elegant. Any other suggestions appreciated.